# StructureMap get appSettings value with XML configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

Is it possible to configure StructureMap in XML that it retrieves constructor parameter value from appSettings?

I am looking for similar XML configuration to this:

```
For<IService>().Use<Service>()
    .Ctor<string>("serviceUrl").EqualToAppSetting("serviceUrl");
```

P.S. The reason for XML configuration is to use stub version of service in development and test environments, but real implementation in production.

Comment: Can't you use the StructureMap profiles functionality instead of XML? Profiles are made for handling having different configurations depending of deployment scenario.

Comment: Haven't used profiles before. Can look at those. Now my workaround is configure service in code, but register stub version in XML. XML configuration overrides code configuration. But I would like to know if I could do same configuration in XML as described in question.